# How to run dynamic Query in Tanstack Query?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been having a rough time understanding `tanstack/query`. I'm trying to fetch data using `tanstack`.

What I'm trying to get is store the data in my state, and then when I press the button, it will pass to my URL and then it will call the button.

```
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    from: "",
    end: "",
    year: "",
    college: "",
    type: "",
  });

  const handleClick = () => {
    
  };
```

This is my sample URL.

> http://localhost:5000/api/result?from=8&end=10&year=23&college=CEIS&type=Students

This is my apicall

```
export const getUsers = async (from, end, year, college , type) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/api/result?from=${from}&end=${end}&year=${year}&college=${college}&type=${type}`)
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    // Handle errors here if needed
    throw error;
  }
};
```

And this is my getResult

```
export const resultQuery = () => {
  const {isPending, error, data ,isFetching} = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["users", data.from, data.end, data.year, data.college, data.type],
    queryFn:  () => getUsers(data.from, data.end, data.year, data.college, data.type)
  })

  return { isPending, error, data, isFetching };
}
```

Comment: Take a look at: https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/react/reference/QueryClient#queryclientfetchquery and https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/react/guides/dependent-queries

Answer (score 0):

Here's a setup using [fetchQuery](https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/react/reference/QueryClient#queryclientfetchquery) that might fit in your case:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import {
  QueryClient,
  QueryClientProvider,
  useQuery,
} from '@tanstack/react-query';
import axios from 'axios';

const queryClient = new QueryClient();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <Example />
    </QueryClientProvider>
  );
}

function queryFn({ id = '1' }) {
  const URL = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/' + id;
  return axios.get(URL).then((res) => res.data);
}

function Example() {
  const { isPending, error, data, isFetching } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ['repoData'],
    queryFn,
  });

  const [state, setState] = useState({
    id: 2,
  });

  async function manualFetch() {
    try {
      const response = await queryClient.fetchQuery({
        queryKey: ['repoData'],
        queryFn: () => queryFn({ id: state.id }),
      });
      console.log({ response });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  if (isPending) return 'Loading...';
  if (error) return 'An error has occurred: ' + error.message;

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Automatic Query</h1>
      <p>Name: {data.name}</p>
      <p>Username: {data.username}</p>
      <p>Email: {data.email}</p>
      <button onClick={manualFetch}>Manual Query for id {state.id}</button>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setState((prevState) => ({ id: prevState.id + 1 }));
        }}
      >
        Increment ID
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The state has been oversimplified along with a dummy JSON placeholder API call, just to make the point.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hello, the problem is I'm not trying to get a single user, I'm trying to get a bunch of objects that is why I'm using the `query` in the `url`, I get the point of single call, what If I want to call an Array of Objects? Like for the example. I will only fetch the data once I click the button.

Comment: If you require multiple calls, perhaps you can look at something like this: https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/framework/react/reference/useQueries